# TFS 2010 PowerTools - Backup plan with SCVMM

Tags: tfs, backup, tfs-power-tools

I set up a TFS environnement with the following specs :

**1st server**
- TFS App-tier + SSRS

**2nd server**
- SCVMM

**3rd server**
- SQL Server (TFS dbs + SSRS db + SCVMM db)

The main issue is regarding SCVMM and Reporting backup.

---

As I couldn't backup SSRS encryption key through the wizard, I followed a procedure from a blod where I had to manually add the SSRS databases to the backup plan into:

**C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\ConfigPT.xml**.

```
 <Reporting>
    <Database Name="ReportServer">xxxxx\TEST_TFS</Database>
    <Database Name="ReportServerTempDb">xxxxx\TEST_TFS</Database>
  </Reporting>
```

It worked nice, but there is no info regarding **SCVMM**.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) states that if SCVMM server is on a separate server than TFS, the DB might not be on TFS data-tier and that it should be backed up separately. However, **VirtualManagerDB share the same SQL instance as TFS.**

---

I feel I could simply add the DB in **ConfigPT.xml** too, but I don't know the xml node name for the SCVMM database.

**Would any of you know this information or any other way to configure backup of SCVMM with PowerTools?**

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just put in the actual name of the DB in the XML.

```
<Database Name="VirtualManagerDB">xxxxx\TEST_TFS</Database>
```

Comment: Hello Dylan, it doesn't need to be nested, as reporting, into something like 
<SCVMM>
<Database Name="VirtualManagerDB">xxxxx\TEST_TFS</Database>
</SCVMM> 
?